# Dejar un espacio abajo del ultimo elemento de un Recycler View Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, recyclerview

Estoy tratando de dejar un espacio abajo del ultimo elemento de un Recycler View pero no se como hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como se ve mi Recycler View, y quiero dejar un espacio porque el Floating Button tapa al mismo boton del elemento.

Quiero se que vea asi como en la app nativa de android de reloj, en la cual al momento de agregar muchos desperadores, si vas al ultimo despertador queda un espacio en el ultimo elemento para no tapar el boton de añadir otro despertador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente agregale un padding abajo y establece el atributo `clipToPadding` en `false` para que sólo lo tenga el último elemento

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    ...
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="72dp" />
```